# Woocommerce hook to detect a new order (not a fake new order) to make a API post request

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to know what hook regards to a successfully payment in Woocommerce checkout (not a fake new order in admin panel) to make a API post request:

```
woocommerce_checkout_order_processed


woocommerce_payment_complete

after_woocommerce_pay

woocommerce_checkout_order_processed

woocommerce_create_order

woocommerce_generate_order_key

woocommerce_new_order_item

woocommerce_order_is_paid

woocommerce_order_payment_status_changed
```

The script I'd like to trigger after the hook is:

```
function get_sold_quantity_and_price($order_id) {
    error_log("------", 3, 'product_changes.log');
    $log_message = "----------------------ID da compra: $order_id----------------------------- \n";
    error_log($log_message, 3, 'product_changes.log');
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    if ($order) {
        $order_items = $order->get_items();

        foreach ($order_items as $item_id => $item) {
            $product = $item->get_product();
            $sku = $product->get_sku();

            $quantity_sold = $item->get_quantity();
            $product_price = $product->get_price();

            $log_message = "SKU Vendido: $sku \n";
            error_log($log_message, 3, 'product_changes.log');
            $log_message = "Preço do SKU acima: $product_price \n";
            error_log($log_message, 3, 'product_changes.log');
            $log_message = "Quantidade do SKU acima: $quantity_sold \n";
            error_log($log_message, 3, 'product_changes.log');
            //API CODE...
        }
    }
}
```